# Defend Kaer Morhen - Choice outcome?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In Kaer Morhen

> at the meeting right before the fight against the Wild Hunt

I have to choose if I want potions or traps be made in the laboratory and if the wall or the forge should be repaired.

My questions here:

1. What will I get if take the potions?
2. What will I get if take the traps?
3. What will happen / will I get if I repair the wall?
4. What will happen / will I get if I repair the forge?

**Update:**

After I got the first answer I've to add that I need a more specific answer e.g. what sword/recipe would I get and do I have to place the traps by myself, are those usable items like bombs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you choose potions you get Superior Swallow, and depending on finishing the side quest "Following the thread" a Fortified Raffard's Decoction.

The traps will kill some enemies in the battle.

Repairing the wall will mean one less wave of enemies attacking.

The forge will result in getting a silver sword.

The general theme is deciding between getting an item or recipe, and directly affecting the battle in some way. Getting the sword and potions might not be a good idea if you're already well equipped.

---

<sub>This information is based on various online guides, they are mostly in agreement but there is also some contradictory information.</sub>

Comment: Are you able to give me a more specific answer? What sword/recipe? Those traps are usable and you've to plant them yourself?

Comment: @Nitro.de You don't need to place the traps yourself as far as I understand. I don't know about the sword, I didn't choose that option. I would suspect that if you kept up with upgrading your witcher gear it is likely to be useless.

Comment: @Nitro.de If you play on a level high enough (or equipped well) to beat your enemies, I would 'take the traps' and 'repair the forge' otherwise the other two choises.

Comment: @PeterCo well i'm lvl 30 but that's not my question i want to know wxactly what i would get

Comment: @Nitro.de It's some garbage sword you will promptly sell/dissemble. I remember brief disappointment then slightly more money.

Comment: The traps are automatic.  I honestly don't think any of the choices make that much of a difference.  But potions/forge will only get you items that you probably have better variants of already, making traps/wall marginally more useful.

Answer (score 2):

I went the traps and the wall. Both are automatic and reduce the numbers of battles needed. Used the YRDEN sign to close the portals (simpler than trying to toss bombs around).
You get a sword and potion if you go the other options but unless you've got to the fight without exploring much of the rest of the game they're likely to be useless.